# Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bits...?

Tags: react-native

X-Code 12, MacoS + M1.

Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support. With err

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaLxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` in `Release`, Clean Build folder and Archive again:

[image: Build Settings > Architectures]

This will force Xcode to build the 64bit binary regardless of what device is connected.

Comment: Tks. 
I'm running a build for testflight

Comment: If my comment can resolve your problem. Please mark accept it. Thank you.

Comment: No. It doesn't solve the problem for me